# Can we load page with html+css+Js into a div as a result of ajax request?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

This is html+ajax code which request another page with html+css+js but as result only html can be loaded into div I need whole page to be loaded in div,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "AjaxTest1.html", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button style="width:50px;height:50px;" onclick="showHint()">Click</button>
<div id="txtHint">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The requested AjaxTest1.html page code is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
input[type=checkbox] {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
</style>
<body id="IGG" onload="myFunction()" style="background-color:#AFF5EA">
<script>
function myFunction(){
        // submisson button
        var del=document.createElement("Input");
        del.type="submit";
        del.value="Delete";
        del.style="margin-left:40%;margin-top:10%;";
        document.getElementById("IGG").appendChild(del);
    }
</script>
<h2>Hello this is fine</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

[Output when i click button to laod AjaxTest1.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u63k9.png)

whereas i need the js and css to also come along with html  in responseText.

Comment: If you want to reload the whole page, you don't really need ajax ...

Comment: no i not reloading the current page which is calling another page through ajax request. I am loading the response text which is html+css+js code into a div on current page.

Comment: you may be right what's possible solution ?

Comment: You can try using [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

Comment: @Oram thanks it worked !